# UIRefreshControlの更新が終わらない

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

以下のコードで、更新しても、画像のように更新が終わりません。
どこが悪いのでしょうか？
Xcodeは7.3です。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

  let data = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n"]
  var refreshCtrl = UIRefreshControl()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.refreshCtrl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.reload), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.addSubview(refreshCtrl)
  }

  func reload() {
    tableView.reloadData()
    refreshCtrl.endRefreshing()
  }

  func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("hoge")
    if cell == nil {
      cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "hoge")
    }
    cell?.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
    return cell!
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }

}
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

この部分ですが、

```
    self.refreshCtrl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.reload), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

`UIRefreshControl`でクリック(タップ)イベントを拾っても仕方ない(そもそもうまく拾えないようですが)ので、こちらの間違いではないかと思います。

```
    self.refreshCtrl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.reload), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
```